# Instagram API Change - Hash tag search API requires OAuth?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, oauth-2.0

Like everyone else, we've recently be graced with Instagram's API update implementing OAuth2-like behavior.

See: http://developers.instagram.com/post/145262544121/instagram-platform-update-effective-june-1-2016

While this is fine n' great for gaining access to user specific data, I can't find anything related to NON-user specific endpoints that seems 'correct'.  In my specific case, the hash-tag search enpoints. (Something that may be now scoped as `public_content` ?)

Documentation: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

It clearly dictates that an `ACCESS-TOKEN` is required. I've tried accessing it with the normal credentials and - no surprise - they don't work.

It seems strange that we are required to use a token that comes with an undisclosed expiration date to access data that isn't user specific?

If our application provides access to the hash-tag search api, do we need to just pick a random user's token to access it?

Comment: Their ruby client appears to answer the question about access tokens.

See:https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem

Definitely requires/includes a token.  #sucks.

Answer (score -1):

The tag endpoints all required the 'public_content' permission, which you do not have by default.

You need to submit your app for review, requesting access to that permission scope, and then (if approved) include it in your oauth header.

Edit:

From https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

"The OAuth 2.0 specification allows you to specify the scope of the access you are requesting from the user. All approved apps have basic access by default, but if you plan on asking for extended access such as reading public content, liking, commenting, or managing friendships, you will need to specify these scopes in your authorization request."

ie:

```
scope=likes+comments
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, maybe I'm slow, but the oauth header you mentioned - doesnt that contain/consist of a user specific token?